# Create header with content code in spreadsheet

Tags: html, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create HTML within my Google Sheets. I have the following structure:

[image: Sample]

The picture is from [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y4dWdTBYMU21ui3VYPpXa5MgnBJCT20bj5pohRnyY94/edit?usp=sharing) spreadsheet which has categories and texts.

I would like to generate the following HTML out of the above category with a formula:

```
<center>Cat1</center>
<div class="boxilistpage">
   <div>Text - 7 - Cat1</div>
   <div>Text - 43 - Cat1</div>
   <div>Text - 64 - Cat1</div>
   <div>Text - 71 - Cat1</div>
</div>
<hr class="pixcode pixcode--separator separator separator--striped" />
<center>Cat2</center>
<div class="boxilistpage">
   <div>Text - 11 - Cat2</div>
   <div>Text - 43 - Cat2</div>
   <div>Text - 32 - Cat2</div>
</div>
<hr class="pixcode pixcode--separator separator separator--striped" />
<center>Cat3</center>
<div class="boxilistpage">
   <div>Text - 37 - Cat3</div>
   <div>Text - 100 - Cat3</div>
   <div>Text - 70 - Cat3</div>
   <div>Text - 47 - Cat3</div>
   <div>Text - 74 - Cat3</div>
</div>
<hr class="pixcode pixcode--separator separator separator--striped" />
```

I am currently trying the following formula:

```
=IF(A2=A3,C2 , "<hr class=" & """pixcode pixcode--separator separator separator--striped""" & " />" & "<div>"&A2&"<div>")
```

However, I get the following output:

[image: Example incorrect output]

I am struggling to create the proper formula that outputs the above HTML text in my spreadsheet.

Comment: So can you explain the actual reason why you want HTML in your spreadsheet? can you not export the data as CSV and generate html from there? it might save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: @Webber The purpose is to create a html structure that we are later using in a web application. It is a one-time exercise, but my Category and Text columns are too large as it would make sense to do it by hand.

Comment: It's possible in spreadsheets, but that would be on the point where i would just create a quick script instead (since the output wont stay in excel either way). So it would be something along the lines of `foreach(lines as line) { if (lastLinesMatch != thisLinesMatch) { add separator and then this line to a new array of lines }}`